# Switch column values by condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 Value 
A    B    -
C    D    +
E    F    +
G    H    -
I    J    -
K    L    -
M    N    -
O    P    +
```

I would like to switch values between `COL1` and `COL2` when the column `Value == "-"`.

Does someone have an idea ?

I guess I should use something like :

```
m = tab['Value'].eq('-')

 np.where(....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use[`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with convert values to numpy array:

```
m = df['Value'].eq('-')

df.loc[m, ['COL1','COL2']] = df.loc[m, ['COL2','COL1']].to_numpy()
print (df)
  COL1 COL2 Value
0    B    A     -
1    C    D     +
2    E    F     +
3    H    G     -
4    J    I     -
5    L    K     -
6    N    M     -
7    O    P     +
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with broadcasting mask:

```
m = df['Value'].eq('-')
df[['COL1','COL2']] = np.where(m.to_numpy()[:, None], 
                               df[['COL2','COL1']], 
                               df[['COL1','COL2']])
```